# Node.js Express API with TypeScript 3 and MongoDB giving me some logical error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express

I want to update a recored, and the code is OK to update record. I am not getting any syntax error.

**Issue**: When I update a record the particular record which I want to update is not updating. It updates the record which display on top.

Maybe I am not sending a the right request.

RecordRouter.ts

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import {RecordComponent} from '../../components';
const router: Router = Router();

router.put('/:id', RecordComponent.update);

export default router;
```

IRepository.ts

```
export interface IRepository<T> {
    put:(T: any)=>Promise<T>;
}
```

In my RecordComponent.ts

```
export async function update(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise <void> {
    try {
        const record: IRecord = await RecordService.put(req.body)

        res.status(201).json(record);
    } catch (error) {
        next(new HttpError(error.message.status, error.message));
    }
}
```

I am using [Node.js Express API with TypeScript 3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-node-express-typescript-api) module for this project.

Comment: what kind of error are you seeing, `TYPEERROR` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I want to edit a record it is not editing the correct record.

Comment: Can you add implementation of RecordService.put

Comment: Would be best if you can add a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please joind codeTogether